# The effect of the following Makefile lines is?

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

Can somebody explain the effect of the following MACRO command please?

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
      $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When make is called with the target that equals what is contained in the variable `$(EXECUTABLE)` (only you can say what that might be), then execute the c compiler with the defined linker flags and compile the objects into the outfile which is named like the target.

So a call to `make myprog` would result in the c compiler creating the executable `myprog`.

Comment: `$(CC)` and `$@` are special targets.  `CC` by default points to your c compiler, and `$@` is the target of the rule being built.    All other variable have to be set within the makefile or be exported by the shell prior to calling make.  In particular `make myprog` does not set `EXECUTABLE` to `myprog`, unless you have the line `EXECUTABLE=$(MAKECMDGOALS)` in the makefile somewhere.  (Where `MAKECMDGOALS` is another special variable).